# defining base frequency, multiplier and divisor for dynamic clock manager

Tags: fpga, frequency, clock, spartan, multiplier

I am using a Spartan 6 xilinx FPGA, I managed to get it all working, changing the multiplier and divisor parameters at runtime. DCM_CLKGEN I use.

My real oscillator is 66.6 MHz, but with PLL_BASE, I can change it. 
As we need a clock frequency from 1 to 100MHz, I am wondering, what base frequency would I take? I set it to 40MHz, just to choose something, that seemed nice....

FREQUENCYout = FREQUENCYbase * MULTIPLIER / DIVISOR

I made a simple spreadsheet to see how different multipliers and divisors convert the base frequency, some divisors on the column headers, some multipliers on each row, so I get a matrix of possible outcome frequencies. Although not for every frequency (It would get bulky). I can't believe trial and error is the way to define those parameters, but surprisingly, I don't find much information on the net about it.

The divisor and multiplier have to be integers (no floating points), otherwise I could just choose "any" multiplier, and calculate a divisor, by completing the equitation.

summary:

- question 1: base frequency for a wide range of output frequencies.
- question 2: a general way of working for defining the multiplier and divisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I know it is primary school mathematics, but I need it every now and then. So I made a quick tool to see if there exists a Divisor and a Multiplier integer (lower than 255 for my application) for a required frequency, or in the neighbourhood of that particular frequency.

it is a public google spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApVM5P9BGwI_dFIwVFdmZHJYX3RVbDBjNVV1YTZsM1E&usp=sharing#gid=3